# Logout and Redirect after signOut

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am trying to log out the user and then redirect to HomePage.

I have done the below ***signOut*** function from firebase 9.0 but the user comes as null.

Ideally would like to log out and remove session data or log out.

```
import React, { useContext, createContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { auth, db } from '../utils/init-firebase';
import {
  confirmPasswordReset,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  sendPasswordResetEmail,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithGoogle,
  signInWithPopup,
  signOut,
} from 'firebase/auth';
import {
  query,
  collection,
  onSnapshot,
  forEach,
  getDoc,
  getDocs,
} from 'firebase/firestore';

const AuthContext = createContext({
  // currentUser: null,
  signInWithGoogle: () => Promise,
  login: () => Promise,
  register: () => Promise,
  logout: () => Promise,
  forgotPassword: () => Promise,
  resetPassword: () => Promise,
});

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

export default function AuthContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [subscription, setSubscription] = useState(null);


  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user ? user : null);
      setIsLoading(false);
      localStorage.setItem('user', true);
      const uid = auth.currentUser?.uid;
        });
      });
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  const [uniqueId, setUniqueId] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setUniqueId(currentUser);
  }, []);

  // console.log('user id from Auth Context==> ', currentUser);

  function login(email, password) {
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  }


  function logout() {
    return signOut(auth);
  }


  const value = {
    currentUser,
    signInWithGoogle,
    login,
    register,
    logout,
    forgotPassword,
    resetPassword,
    isLoading,
    subscription,
  };

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
}
```

Comment: `but the user comes as null.` can you clarify what you mean? What user variable is null, and when? How is what's happening different than what you want to happen?

Comment: Wouldn't `currentUser` be filled with the previous user's info each time the `onAuthStateChanged` listener fires? So if a user just logged out `user` will be `null`, but `currentUser` would have the info about the user that just logged out?

Comment: @Nathan...
The error looks like below.


react_devtools_backend.js:4026 Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Comment: @samthecodingman I am guessing the same , however, the error occurs after signOut component derived from firebase auth so I was hoping it will resolve by itself

Comment: "FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions" implies that somewhere else in your code, not shown here, you aren't properly unsubscribing a listener when `currentUser` changes. Check your `useEffect` calls for any missing `currentUser`/`uid` entries in their dependencies and make sure they properly handle when those values are `null`/`undefined`.